# Apple ID - Security questions reset

Tags: icloud, security, apple-id

When I'm logging into my Apple ID (https://appleid.apple.com/account/home) in the tab "Password and Security" there are security questions, just like this article says: http://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT201485

The thing is - I know answers to my security questions, I keep them in text file, just like my other accounts, so I have no chance to forget them. But nevertheless my answers are not right according to what the page says when I click "Continue".

Ok, I thought, then I'll try to reset my security questions. I read the article that I mentioned before (HT201485), but the thing is - there is no link to "Send reset security info email to [rescue email address]". And I do have 2 additional e-mail addresses.

I also checked the source code of the page. And guess what I've found:

[image]

"*TODO add ability to reset CRs via rescue email*"? That's above good and evil.

I know, that's very likely a duplicate, but I have some information that might help others with simular situation (in the my own answer below) and also I have a question:

How is it possible that my 100% correct answers suddenly became incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And that's the solution to my case.

I called to Apple Support and they said, that **none of my additional e-mails was "rescue"**. I remember perfectly that in the time I registered my Apple ID there was no such option - just ability to set additional e-mail.

So, support reseted my security questions and now I can set a new ones, along with setting the rescue e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just update this by adding that the ability to send a security question reset to your recovery email is now present at iforgot.apple.com. Note that you still need a recovery email in your account, or a linked device, for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

My experience was quite frustrated but in the end I got my security questions reset!

I am in China and I have not used my US-based apple id for a while but just my China-based apple id. So when I tried to login my US-based apple id for the first time in the past several months I was required to answer my security questions then iCloud replied the answers were wrong. I was pretty sure some answers were correct so I tried several times to let iCloud give me other questions but iCloud kept complaining some answers were wrong. After I tried 5 or 6 times they locked my account. When I tried to reset my question the server replied we can't verify your id to let you do that.

I called apple China customer support and they told me there is little them can do too, I better not use this account any more. They also told me the reset procedure is the same whether I am in China or US, which means even if I called apple US customer support I probably get the same answer.

After that I tried iCloud everyday (when they unlock my account) to see if it would let me reset my question. After I tried the 5th time and I didn't even expect it would let me do iCloud suddenly showed the reset page and let me reset it! I don't even know why they let me do it this time.